# How to transfer data and columns headers from CSV to Sqlite3 - python 3.7 - windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, csv, tkinter

**What i am trying to do:**

Basically i need to transfer all data and columns header in csv (it's a list of clients, that will be update periodically) into a sqlite3

**What is my issue:**

i found online the script below that allow me to transfer the data from CSV to sqlite3, but the headers are not "pasted" as headers but are pasted like normal data

(if you print the sqlite table, you will see that the column headers row is with ID = 0, but ID = 0 should start from the first client record which is D099, RR Limited)

Can you help me please?

```
#drop table used to be able to update sqlite
def drop_table():
    conn=sqlite3.connect("city_spec.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MyTable")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()


#transfer data from excel to sqlite3 -
def transfer():
    drop_table()
    df2 = pd.read_csv('iris_clients3.csv', names=['Client Code', 'Client Name', 'Contact name', 'YE'])

    # strip whitespace from headers
    df2.columns = df2.columns.str.strip()

    con = sqlite3.connect("city_spec.db")

    # drop data into database
    df2.to_sql("MyTable", con)

    con.close()

#this function will help to print the database

def write_to_csv2():
    transfer()
    conn=sqlite3.connect("city_spec.db")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM MyTable")
    for row in cur.fetchall(): #if want to print uncomment
        print(row)
    conn.close()

write_to_csv2()
```

[image]

[image]

Thank you

Comment: This "_transfer all data and columns header in csv_" is confusing because then the question seems to want to get rid of the "columns header" row. You might find the solution if you study the "name" and "header" arguments in the [pandas read_csv doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: Hi, thank you, i red that document that you linked, canghed the line df2 = pd.read_csv('iris_clients3.csv', names=['Client Code', 'Client Name', 'Contact name', 'YE']) ..... in ..... df2 = pd.read_csv('iris_clients3.csv', headers=0) and i removed this line df2.columns = df2.columns.str.strip() but nothing changed,  it stil import only the data without columns from csv to sqlite3. Other tips? thank you @DinoCoderSaurus

Answer (score 0):

- `df2 = pd.read_csv('iris_clients3.csv', names=['Client Code', 'Client Name', 'Contact name', 'YE'])`

  says "*These are my column names, load all the data as rows*"
- `df2 = pd.read_csv('iris_clients3.csv', header=0)`

  says "*The first row is column names, do not load it as data*"
- `df2 = pd.read_csv('iris_clients3.csv', names=['Client Code', 'Client Name', 'Contact name', 'YE'],header=0)`

  says "*These are the column names, ignore (do not load) row 1*"

If you are trying to replace the names in row 1 with column names that do not contain space (*really* good idea!), use the third syntax and remove the spaces from the list, ie `['ClientCode, 'ClientName'.....]`)

NB while running a repro, it gave the following warning from this line `df2.columns = df2.columns.str.strip()`

> UserWarning: The spaces in these column names will not be changed. In
> pandas versions < 0.14, spaces were converted to underscores.